# Python Pandas - Compared a value in a row to two different values from two different columns in previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So i have a dataframe df:

```
Date    High  Low   Open
2/5/21   100   10     50
3/5/21   110    5     65
4/5/21   220  180    200
```

I want to see if the open of the day falls in the range of the previous day using if statements. I want to use if statements because i might want to add more conditions in the future.

I tried creating a function:

```
def openloc(row):
    if row['Open'] <= row['High'].shift(-1) & row['Open'] >= row['Low'].shift(-1):
        return 'Yes'

df['inrange?'] = df.apply(openloc, axis = 1)
```

But i keep getting the error : 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'

Is there a better way to do this?

My desied output would be this:

```
Date    High  Low   Open  Inrange?
2/5/21   100   10     50   nan
3/5/21   110    5     65   yes
4/5/21   220  180    200   no
```

I dont want to return a boolean because eventually i might want to add more info than yes or no

Comment: You're calling `apply` on axis=1. Meaning you're running `openloc` on a single row. For that reason `row['High']` is the _number_ 100 (for example) not a column that can be shifted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *vectorized* operations, without apply, using `between` and `shift`:

```
df.assign(Inrange = df.Open.between(df.Low.shift(-1), df.High.shift(-1))
                           .shift()
                           .map({True:'Yes', False:'No'}))


     Date  High  Low  Open Inrange
0  2/5/21   100   10    50     NaN
1  3/5/21   110    5    65     Yes
2  4/5/21   220  180   200      No
```

Comment: Cheers, just what i was looking for! Just a side question, if i wanted to add more conditions, such as: between AND higher than 100 return 'Higher that 100' would this be possible through this method?

Comment: @elzzup, yes, that would require you to combine the conditions before applying shift and map

Comment: Hey i actually noticed upon implementation that its not giving me the correct result. From what i can see if the open is greater than the high it will return a yes value

Comment: the code is based on the shared data ... kindly share an updated data that reflects this incorrect result, and what the expected result should be. Pls share it in your original question, so others can attempt it as well

Comment: So this is the code i used, to get the output i wanted. instead of shifting -1, i shifted 1. `df.assign(Inrange = df.Open.between(df.Low.shift(-1), df.High.shift(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

An [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) option:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2/5/21', '3/5/21', '4/5/21'],
                   'High': [100, 110, 220],
                   'Low': [10, 5, 180],
                   'Open': [50, 65, 200]})

m = df['Open'].between(df['Low'].shift(-1), df['High'].shift(-1))
df['inrange?'] = np.where(m, 'Yes', 'No')
df['inrange?'] = df['inrange?'].shift()
print(df)
```

```
     Date  High  Low  Open inrange?
0  2/5/21   100   10    50      NaN
1  3/5/21   110    5    65      Yes
2  4/5/21   220  180   200       No
```